# How to implement parallel processing using CUDA in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, parallel-processing, cuda

I have installed CUDA toolkit and download some libraries and exported to my Java project in Netbeans. I never using CUDA before and I am very interesting to learn for my parallel algorithm. My question is:

1. How I know that my environment is ready to use CUDA? Is there any code to check it in Java?
2. I need a best practice to implement parallel processing using CUDA in Java? Is there anybody that has simple parallel code that I can use to learn CUDA?

Answer (score 1):

If this is your first time using Cuda, I would highly recommend using the [language it was designed for (C/C++)](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-quick-start-guide/index.html). Cuda is only available through java through bindings like [JCuda](http://www.jcuda.org/). Using these bindings reduces your example code sample size and support pool, along with adding yet another thing that can go wrong. More complexity, more problems.

If you do insist on using JCuda, here are their [official sample projects](https://github.com/jcuda/jcuda-samples/tree/master/JCudaSamples).

As for testing if your "environment" is ready to use cuda, you can check your cuda version in a command prompt with `nvcc -V`. If the command is unrecognized, something is wrong.

You can use `nvcc` to compile the [sample projects](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html) that should have come with your cuda installation. I believe by default on windows they are located in `C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\`.

Comment: nvcc -V is working. I will try the samples that you have mentioned above. thanks @Thane